# Optimizing file write C

Tags: c, performance, file

how can I improve speed while working with a file?
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>


void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
  char temp;
  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;
}


void permute(char *a, int l, int r)
{
  int i;
  if (l == r) {
    printf("%s\n", a);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "a");
    fprintf(fp,"%s\n", a );

    fclose(fp);
  }

  else
  {
    for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
    {
      swap((a+l), (a+i));
      permute(a, l+1, r);
      swap((a+l), (a+i)); //backtrack
    }
  }
}


int main()
{
  remove("test.txt");
  struct timeval  tv1, tv2;
  gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
  char str[] = "ABCD";
  int n = strlen(str);
  permute(str, 0, n-1);

  gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
  printf ("Total time = %f seconds\n",
  (double) (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000000 +
  (double) (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec));


  return 0;
}
```

If I run it saving the permutations to a file I get `Total time = 0.161452 seconds`

Without saving permutations to a file I get `Total time = 0.00000 seconds`

Thanks!

Comment: You are opening and closing the file to write each loop....

Comment: It's not just a loop, it's recursive. You should open your file before entering the recursive function, so it would open only once.

Comment: Opening writing and closing file takes time  you do it not one time. What do you want to optimize?

Comment: File-operations are typically slow compared to in-memory operations. You could speed it up a little by avoiding the parsing of the format string that `printf` must do, and use [`fputs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs) instead.

Comment: If that doesn't give you the speed you need, you may need to buffer your data in memory and write it to the file in larger chunks.

Comment: And besides, the time writing to file will only increase marginally as you increase the length of the string. And is it really a problem? Less than 0.2 of a second is barely noticeable for users of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Basic optimizations:

- Leave the file open for as long as you write to it.
- There is no need to remove the file at start up, you can as well `"w"` write to it and it will have the same effect.
- Replace recursion with a loop.

These will make a vast difference. Opening a file takes lots of time, as does writing to it or removing it. Everything file-related are the main bottlenecks in this program.

As for the recursion, you have written a version that isn't likely tail-call optimized, so it will bloat up the stack needlessly.

Advanced optimizations:

- Separate algorithm from printing to screen and/or file. Store all results in a RAM buffer. When done, print to screen or file.
- Outsource printing to file to a dedicated thread, which can chew away on the file write in the background while the main thread does other things. That way, the file write isn't a slow, blocking call.
- Investigate the algorithm itself. Could you do things in different order? Minimize the number of branches?

Micro-optimizations (will only have a small effect):

- Replace `strlen` with `sizeof`.
- Replace `printf`/`fprintf` with `puts`/`fputs`.
- `restrict` qualify the pointers in `swap` (probably not needed since it should get inlined).

Answer (score 0):

Try open/close file only once, in the `main()` function, like below:

```
void permute(char *a, int l, int r, FILE *fp)
{
    int i;
    if (l == r) 
    {
        printf("%s\n", a);
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", a);
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
        {
            swap((a+l), (a+i));
            permute(a, l+1, r, fp);
            swap((a+l), (a+i)); //backtrack
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    remove("test.txt");
    struct timeval  tv1, tv2;
    gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
    char str[] = "ABCD";
    int n = strlen(str);

    // open file
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "a");

    permute(str, 0, n-1, fp);

    // close file
    fclose(fp);

    gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
    printf ("Total time = %f seconds\n",
        (double) (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000000 +
        (double) (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec));

    return 0;
}
```